# How do I convert jQuery AJAX code to vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an AJAX script in jQuery that I am trying to convert to vanilla Javascript. I Can't seem to convert this. How would I convert this to vanilla JavaScript?

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'csv_data.csv',
  dataType: 'text',
}).done(successFunction);

$('body').append(table);
```

Comment: That is plain javascript. Do you mean you don't want to use jQuery?

Comment: fetch(url, request).then(function(respose) { successFunction(response)})

Comment: You can check the source code of jquery on github

Comment: [How to make an AJAX call without jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `XMLHttpRequest`

```
var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
r.open('GET', 'csv_data.csv');
r.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (r.readyState != 4 || r.status != 200) return;
    successFunction(r.responseText);
};
r.send();
```

Haven't tested it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) API for Ajax request.

```
fetch("csv_data.csv", { headers: { "Content-Type": "text/csv" } })
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.txt();
  })
  .then(successFunction);
document.body.appendChild(table);
```